# C struct list incompatible pointer type

Tags: c, list, pointers

I'm trying to work on a struct list defined like this:

```
typedef struct {
    item_s item;
    struct node_s *next;
} node_s;
```

when i try to do this:

```
...
node_s *newnode = malloc(sizeof(node_s));
node_s *newnode = malloc(sizeof(node_s));

head->next = newnode
```

it gives this error: "assignment to 'struct node_s *' from incompatible pointer type 'node_s *' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]"
It seems like the "struct node_s *" is a different pointer type than a pointer to the struct defined as "node_s *". Im a bit confused.

I tried to define the "next" pointer inside the struct as "node_s *" but as i expected it didn't work because the struct node_s itself is not yet defined.

Comment: `typedef struct {` -> `typedef struct node_s {`. The `struct node_s *next;` (forward) declares a pointer to a `struct` you haven't defined

Answer (score 5):

The type `node_s` is defined, but not the type `struct node_s`.

```c
// Defines `struct node_s`.
struct node_s {
    item_s item;
    struct node_s *next;
};

// Defines `node_s` as an alias for `struct node_s`.
typedef struct node_s node_s;
```

They can be combined:

```c
typedef struct node_s {
    item_s item;
    struct node_s *next;
} node_s;
```

Note how the struct is named here, but anonymous in the OP's code.

---

Placing the typedef first is possible.

```c
// Defines `node_s` as an alias for `struct node_s`.
typedef struct node_s node_s;

// Defines `struct node_s`.
struct node_s {
    item_s item;
    struct node_s *next;
};
```

This allows the maximum avoidance of `struct node_s`.

```c
// Defines `node_s` as an alias for `struct node_s`.
typedef struct node_s node_s;

// Defines `struct node_s`.
struct node_s {
    item_s item;
    node_s *next;          // <---
};
```

Comment: Alternatively, typedef _before_: `typedef struct node_s node_s; struct node_s { item_s item; node_s *next; };`

Comment: @Chris, Added _